# Legend in Matplotlib -- Subplotting by a For loop

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend

I'm new to Python and Matplotlib, I would appreciate any help on how to create legends for every subplot that I have created with a FOR loop. Here is the code and the best that I could get close to labeling my figures.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n_rows=2
n_cols=2
leg=['A','B','C','D']
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows,n_cols)
for row_num in range(n_rows):
    for col_num in range (n_cols):
    ax = axes[row_num][col_num]
    ax.plot(np.random.rand(20))
    ax.set_title(f'Plot ({row_num+1}, {col_num+1})')
    ax.legend(leg[row_num+col_num])   
fig.suptitle('Main Title')
fig.tight_layout()               
plt.show()
```

here is the output of the code:
[Image with incorrect legends](https://i.stack.imgur.com/59RSq.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `ax.legend(leg[row_num+col_num])` but `row_num+col_num` is not a correct representation for an index of a list.

This is what is happening

```
row_num | col_num | idx=row_num+col_num |  leg[idx]
    0   |     0   |  0                  |    A
    0   |     1   |  1                  |    B
    1   |     0   |  1                  |    B
    1   |     1   |  2                  |    C
```

If you use `leg[row_num+col_num]` you get the incorrect legend entry.

There are many ways to fix this. A simple one is to introduce a counter (the variable `j` in the code below), which increments at every loop.

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
n_rows=2
n_cols=2
leg=['A','B','C','D']
fig, axes = plt.subplots(n_rows,n_cols)
j = 0
for row_num in range(n_rows):
    for col_num in range(n_cols):
        ax = axes[row_num][col_num]
        ax.plot(np.random.rand(20))
        ax.set_title(f'Plot ({row_num+1}, {col_num+1})')
        ax.legend(leg[j]) 
        j += 1
fig.suptitle('Main Title')
fig.tight_layout()               
plt.show()
```

Comment: Davide_sd, I can't believe I spent hours fixing this. Thanks for your response. A great help.

Comment: Don't forget to mark this answer as the solution to the question :)